# Powershell Select-Object and Alter Property Names when modifying values

Tags: powershell

I have a Cmdlet Get-AdUser that I am piping to a select object and in that select running a function on the AccountExpires property to convert the Property Value to a date value.

My question is when the object is output the column heading is no longer friendly and inherits the function used to return the new value. How do I form the statement so a friendly name is output? Was hoping to not have to assemble my own PSObject.

```
Get-AdUser "some.account" -Properties AccountExpires | select Enabled, Name, $({[datetime]$d =$_.AccountExpires; ConvertTo-Date($d)})
```

I then get a resulting table header of...

```
Enabled       True       [datetime]$d =$_.AccountExpires; ConvertTo-Date($d)
-------       -----      ----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an expression hashtable of `@{E={scriptblock};L="Label"}`.

`select Enabled, Name, @{E={$({[datetime]$d =$_.AccountExpires; ConvertTo-Date($d)})};L="AccountExpires"}`

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx for more information on creating custom selected objects.

Comment: The change was to minimal for me to edit but I had to modify the statement slightly. Was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much! `Select-Object SamAccountName, Name, @{E={[datetime]$d =$_.AccountExpires; ConvertTo-Date($d)};L="AccountExpires"}`